# How to create named credentials using apex

Tags: apex

"In a scenario where we need to create Auth Providers and Named Credentials dynamically and include them in a managed package, I have successfully created an Auth Provider using Apex. Now, how can I create a Named Credential and associate it with the Auth Provider Dynamically using apex?"

AuthProvider class

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/419118/how-to-create-auth-provider-using-apex